# Get Total Pages Count and Current Page QuickLook

Tags: ios, swift, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using 'QLPreviewController' to show document file (pdf/doc).
Is there any way to get Total number of pages and also current page number?

Or any other way to view pdf/doc and also get page counts.
[image]

Like "9 of 9"- How to get that

Comment: Right now quicklook only supports PDF page highlight and for other types like doc or docx its not supporting for paging & current page count app.

Comment: @CodeChanger On "docx" files too I'm getting Page highlight. Also any other way by which I can open docx/pdf n also get the page highlight.

Comment: Which IOS version you have as I am checking it on latest OS on my iPhone and its not showing current page heighlighter.

Comment: @CodeChanger Yes, you r correct. So any other way by which I can get? Apart from viewing file in 'QuickLook'

Comment: so you want only count and current page or also want to show current page and total page on Doc file ?

Comment: Only count and current page. @CodeChanger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QuickLook only for look mate. You could get metadata from CGPDFDocument

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourFileNameHere", withExtension: "pdf"),
        let pdf = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) {
        let count = pdf.numberOfPages
        print(count)
    }
```

For docx, try install ZipZap with carthage: `github "pixelglow/ZipZap" "8.1"`

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"demo" withExtension:@"docx"];
    ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithURL:url error:nil];
    NSString *pageCount;
    for (ZZArchiveEntry* entry in archive.entries) {
    if([entry.fileName isEqualToString:@"docProps/app.xml"]) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
        [entry newDataWithError:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //Get the value between tag <Pages> and </Pages>
        NSRange tag1 = [responseString rangeOfString:@"<Pages>"];
        NSRange tag2 = [responseString rangeOfString:@"</Pages>"];
        pageCount = [responseString substringWithRange: 
        NSMakeRange((tag1.location + tag1.length), (tag2.location - tag1.length - tag1.location))];
    }
}
```

Here the source for metadata of docx: https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_(DOCX)

Comment: ''HP Smart' app does. They shows pages count. There must be some way to get .docx page counts.

Comment: Just update with docx. Code in Objc due to not sure why  `ZZArchive ` missing some API in swift

Comment: Thanks. But by this way I'm not getting on which Page user is currently. Like in QuickLook how it shows on upper left corner "2 of 9".

Comment: @Nitesh- how it shows on upper left corner "2 of 9". Ans: apple does not provided any public api related to this, if you want "2 of 9" then use UIwebview instead of QuickLook

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik In UIWebview I can fetch that ?